# Dummit & Foote <Abstract Algebra> Exercise 8.2.4

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I'm trying to solve Exercise 8.2.4 in Dummit & Foote

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. Prove that if the following conditions hold then R is a Principal domain
>
> (1) any two nonzero elements $a$ and $b$ in $R$ have a greatest common divisor which can be written in the form $ra+sb$ for some $r,s$ $\in R$, and
>
> (2) if $a_1, a_2 , \cdots ,a_n, \cdots $ are nonzero elements of $R$ such that $a_{i+1} | a_i $, then there is a positive integer $N$ such that $a_n $ is a unit times $a_N$ for all $n \ge N$

I tried to understand the solution in

https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/integral-domains-satisfying-bezouts-identity-and-having-divisibility-minimal-elements-are-pids/

But I am stuck from the outset.

In the solution I put a link above, it claims then for any nonzero ideal $I$ in the ring $R$ of the problem, when we put partial order on $I$ as divisibility relation like

> $$x \leq y \; \text{if} \; y|x $$

then each chain $C$ in $I$ with such partial order is a countable sequence $\lbrace C_i \rbrace$ with $C_{i+1} | C_i$

But why should this hold? Does divisibility partial order on (an ideal of) an integral domain make each chain be countable? This seems highly nontrivial and even seems wrong..

Any comment on the claim in the above link or on the problem itself will be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible. If the link ever dies, this question will be virtually meaningless.

Comment: It is not true that every chain (by which I assume they mean totally ordered subset) need be a sequence. Instead, what you should do is suppose that some chain has no upper bound. It will follow that you can find a strictly increasing sequence, contradicting your hypothesis.